# How to translate the phrase "just because . . . it doesn't mean that..."?

Tags: translation

I want to be able to say something along the line of:

"just because she has a boyfriend doesn't mean she can't focus in school."

Comment: searching jukuu for "just because" yields the max number 100 of example sentences, many of which also contain "does not mean that", among 1st 20 note the following:。。。并不意味着、不是因为。。。，就意味着、不能仅仅因为。。。就认为、虽然。。。但并不意味着、仅仅因为。。。并不意味着、。。。但这并不意味着、

Answer (score 1):

This is a translation close enough for your purposes probably:
她有了男朋友不代表她上课不专心

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to translate this phrase.

1. **不要仅因为**......**就代表/觉得/是/意味着）**......

   不要仅因为她谈男朋友了，就觉得她不会将心思放在学习上。

   just because, translated to "不要仅因为"，we put the negative "doesn't mean" ahead in Chinese grammer. "that" can be translated to "就觉得，就代表"
2. **仅仅/只是**......**并不意味着**......

   她只是谈了男朋友，并不代表她不会将心思花在学业上。

   This is the literal translation. But it also makes sense.

Comment: I would interpret the first sentence "不要仅因为她谈男朋友了，就觉得她不会将心思放在学习上。" as telling the listener "Don't think that she can't focus in school just because she has a boyfriend." and the second sentence "她只是谈了男朋友，并不代表她不会将心思花在学业上。" as "She just has a boyfriend, that doesn't mean she can't focus in school." as opposed to directly telling the listener what not to think. Slightly different, but both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

儘管(雖然 etc.)。。。。不代表（不表示 etc.）

儘管她有男朋友，不代表她不能專注學業